# Does WPC flooring need expansion gaps / transition strips for distances greater than 40 feet?

Tags: flooring

I know laminate requires expansion gaps every 40 ft, but wood plastic composite flooring is made of a different core, does it expand as much?

The manufacturers instructions doesn't even mention it.

Comment: I thought the plastic composite flooring expanded more than wood composit.

Answer (score 0):

what is the product,  each product change from manufactur to manufactur. a quick call to tech support will answer that question easily. but if your you dont want to call them then i break the floor apart at each door way or hall. also pay attention to any window or patio glass doors with direct sunlight blast through them, that heat will absolutely make it grow in crazy amounts, and when the rest of the floor is cold you will get insane buckling.

Comment: So "I don't know" and "maybe"? :P